# Opencart coding syntax

Tags: php, opencart

I'm trying to learn opencart development but I'm new to PHP.so please help undestand the following syntax.

```
private $error = array();
protected function validate() {
    if (utf8_strlen(trim($this->request->post['guest_name'])) < 1) {
        $this->error['guest_name'] = $this->language->get('error_guest_name');
    }

    if (utf8_strlen(trim($this->request->post['guest_message'])) < 1) {
        $this->error['guest_message'] = $this->language->get('error_guest_message');
    }

    return !$this->error;
}
```

Now my question is what does !$this->error return . error is an array and what does `!$this->error` mean.

Also please suggest me some good tutorials for Learning PHP from beginner to Advanced including OOPs and Framework.
And opencart development tutorials as well.
Thankyou.

Comment: `NOT $this->error` so if error array is empty returns TRUE and if there are occurances in error then FALSE

Comment: Also  could you suggest some Tutorial/content for Learning PHP from beginner to Advanced including OOPs and Framework @RiggsFolly

Comment: We are not supposed to do that. But Google will help you

Comment: Sure,thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

This youtube videos playlist can also be helpful to become OpenCart developer Gurus:

[OpenCart Videos Tutorials](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7Q641RjdJY4&list=PLJrQQAOTh1X_QDKxUsfmIuteb-VXkBDNe)

1. [Opencart tutorials posts](https://webocreation.com/blog/opencart-tutorial/)
2. [OpenCart installation localhost](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZeTJKjlgRLg) This video go through the OpenCart installation in localhost
3. [Files and folder structure of Opencart](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kCDqw7kcqLQ) It describes files and folders structure of OpenCart
4. [Creating Database Table schema in OpenCart](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=w8Uay-QvHFg) It shows database table schema and shows how to create database tables in OpenCart
5. [OpenCart Library Predefined Objects’ Methods](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EdJFjJek_3Y) It describes OpenCart Library Predefined Objects’ Methods and shows where to find them.
6. [MVCL pattern, code flow and request & response in OpenCart](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=X6bsMmReT-4) It shows MVCL pattern, code flow and request & response in OpenCart. 
   They describe the flow as in the picture below:
   [image: MVCL described with Code]
7. [Install, Configure and Uninstall Opencart module](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mXhRSXw_ycE) It shows three ways to upload modules, then install, configure and uninstall the OpenCart 3 module/extension.
8. [Layouts and position in Opencart 3](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=l5I0nwQs27g) It describes the OpenCart 3 layouts and positions. It shows how to show customize layouts for different pages, giving examples of categories pages. We show the different layout for a different category.
9. [Event overview of Opencart](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_aH2hiUK-jo) You will learn what Events are in OpenCart, how they work and what makes them so useful.
10. [Opencart API documentation for developer](https://youtu.be/bc2govdEiuA) This video will show how to use and make custom opencart API
11. [Opencart Module Development: Single Instance module, Form creation, validation, and submission to the database](https://webocreation.com/blog/opencart-development-single-instance-module-form-validate-save-in-db/)
12. [Single Instance module frontend login module, Opencart 3 documentation](https://webocreation.com/blog/single-instance-module-frontend-login-module-opencart-3-documentation/)
13. [Opencart 3 development tutorial, multi-instance slider testimonials module](https://webocreation.com/blog/opencart-3-module-development-tutorial-multi-instance-slider-testimonials/)
14. [Opencart 3 module development tutorial, multi-instance testimonial free](https://webocreation.com/blog/opencart-3-module-development-tutorial-multi-instance-testimonial-free/)

Once you see these videos and posts then it will help you a lot to understand the Opencart flows :)

Comment: Thank you.Could you please make a video explaining the coding  as well